# Rspec/FactoryBot reads my previous schema.db file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-6

In recent change I've combined columns first_name and last_name into a one full_name. I did a migration and on my schema.rb everything is up to date. My User factory now looks like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  password = Faker::Internet.password

  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    full_name { Faker::Name.name }
    password { password }
    password_confirmation { password }
    owner { 1 }
    registration_step { :finished }
    confirmed_at { Time.current }
  end
end
```

However when I try tu run my rspec I get repeated error:

> ```
>   Failure/Error: let(:user) { create :user }
>   
>   NoMethodError:
>     undefined method `full_name=' for #<User:0x00007ff5e597e310>
> ```

Moreover running *RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate*  somehow rewrites my schema.db into a previous state where first_name and last_name still existed instead of full_name. Those columns don't exist in my migration files anymore!

How FactoryBot/rspec is still able to load my old version of schema and how to fix this issue?

**Note** I used *rails db:drop db:create db:migrate* but it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rails db:test:prepare` to set the test db schema equal to your schema.rb file.

You probably rollbacked a migration on development and re-ran it after changing it, but on test it ran with the old code and doesn't run again since it already did once.

Migrating test database is something that you shouldn't need to do. Just set the schema with `rails db:test:prepare`.